# How do I cut triangles out of a concave Delaunay triangulation?

Tags: polygon, triangulation, delaunay, concave

I'm using Delaunay to triangulate a concave polygon, but it fills in the concavities. How do I automatically remove the triangles that are outside the polygon boundaries?

Comment: Is this what you actually want to do?  The Delaunay edges may cross the polygon edges, so using this to triangulate a polygon is not going to always give you a valid triangulation of the polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-answer: in some cases, this is impossible. I needed to use a constrained Delaunay algorithm: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.delaunay.html

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't, you should find a Delauney routine that handles boundaries correctly.

Alternately you could, assuming you know the edges, go through every triangle and delete those that cross an edge.
Search for segment-segment interestion tests for code to do this.